# Laravel 4: include template with parameters in single line

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to save a blade template into a javascript variable but I can't figure out how to remove the line breaks from the template.

I looked at extending blade and created the following code based on `BladeCompiler:compileInclude()` which removes all line breaks, but only for templates without parameters.

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('include_string');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $__env->make($2, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array(\'__data\', \'__path\')))->render()); ?>', $view);
});
```

I know I could simply remove all line breaks from the template manually but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Has anyone done this before? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to create your own blade functions that can receive multiple values (or an array) and I don't think it is even possible by using "only" `Blade::extend`. Of course you could extend Laravel's `BladeCompiler` class and write much more powerful macros.

But instead I suggest you create a macro for removing the line breaks only.

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('singleline');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $2); ?>', $view);
});
```

And the use it either like this:

```
@singleline(View::make('view-name', array('foo' => 'bar')))
```

Or if you prefer the `$__env` syntax:

```
@singleline($__env->make('view-name', array('foo' => 'bar')))
```

Comment: This works exactly like expected, thanks. I tried nesting blade functions before but for some reason I never thought of using plain PHP..

Comment: You're welcome. Yep nesting blade functions sadly doesn't work because they return a string with `<?php echo ...`